# Artificiall Intelligence - Vacuum cleaner

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I neeed to code a intelligent agent that sucks dirt. My agent gets perception from the world and then acts.

The world is a 2-dimensional array. Every array item can be "clean", "bump" or "dirt".

Te problem i have is how to navigate my vacuum cleaner ? Which direction should I take when i come to a wall ? Should i go left, right or back ?  Is there a suitable algorithm for this kind of problem ?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @moooeeeep The `homework` tag should not be used anymore: [Trogdor ate my homework (tag)!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag)

Comment: Can your agent remember previous decisions?

Comment: @Baz I'd guess it's a Markov Decision Process.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply random action selection your agent will have visited all fields of the map after infinitely many time steps. This may provide you an initial baseline solution.

The question reads like you probably should look into graph-based search algorithms or potentially Dynamic Programming to solve this. I would recommend reading Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, by Russell & Norvig, chapters 2 and 3.